# System.AbortJob not working?

Tags: salesforce, apex

I'm trying to figure out how to get System.AbortJob() to actually work. My assumption (could be wrong) is that when I pass the current jobId to System.AbortJob(), the job will stop right there and abort. Here is my test that isn't working, as I am seeing the System.debug() showing up in my logs.

Executing from execute anonymous:

```
queueableTest tst = new queueableTest();
System.enqueueJob(tst);
```

Queueable class:

```
public class queueableTest implements Queueable {

    public static void execute(QueueableContext Context)
    {
        ID jobID = Context.getJobId();
        System.AbortJob(jobID);
        shouldntExecute();
    }


    public static void shouldntExecute()
    {
        System.debug('Why is this executing?');        
    }

}
```

Any help/feedback greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The `System.abortJob()` call will only take effect after its execution context is completed. Since you are calling abortJob from the same context that you want to abort, by the time it takes effect your code has already finished executing which makes the `System.abortJob()` call irrelevant.

If you want to abort the current job, you need to use `return;` or `System.assert(false, 'Aborting');` In the first case your job will terminate with a status of 'Completed', and in the second case with a 'Failed' status. Throwing an exception would also have the same result.